# Missing parenthesis Error when building MATERIALIZED

Tags: sql, oracle, intersect, materialized-views

So I'm trying to build a complex materilized view, but I somehow don't know what I'm writing wrong

But for educational purposes, I'm trying to reverse the query while removing the joins and using intersection instead, even thought the query is working perfectly, but I do need to do it using intersections

It's been few hours I'm working on it and always having this error message

> 907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: It is completely unclear what your query do. It make no sense to use `intersect` if you still use the same table. Please describe logic of your query.and table structure. Problem here is not missing parenthesis or `materialized view` the problem is query itself. So either build your select steo by step or describe what you need. From your query it is very hard to guess what you want to obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query makes no sense. There is `)` in `having` which has no left parenthesis. 
`INTERSECT` is done on queries that return different number of columns. 
You use `moe1` and `moe2` aliases where they are undefined.

Please rather describe your table and tell what you want to query. It is very hard to guess your logic looking on the query.

Comment: Thank you , I actually wrote the original query , but sadly once it's resolved I must change real attributes to dummy values

Comment: @napi15 I would expect not query but table structure like: `tableA (col1 number, col2 varchar2(20) ...)` and description what do you want to calculate

Answer (score 1):

1. Check ")" - need 1 more
2. INTERSECT - use it then you want exclude some rows. I think you need Inner (Or Left) JOIN .

Comment: Thank you for the advice , but for educational purpose , I must avoid using a jointure , thank you